# Risks in using Neo4j as a stand-alone database

Tags: mysql, mongodb, graph, neo4j

I have seen quite a few products with graph-related data models built on both Neo4j and a relational or document database. The other db is generally used to store the metadata of each node.

I am considering building a product relying entirely on Neo4j, storing all my objects' metadata as node properties. Is there any caveat in doing so?

Answer (score 2):

Entirely depends of how much metadata you want to store. 10 primitive / short String properties per node is absolutely fine. 1000 large JSON documents per node... not so much. It isn't a document store.

What sort of numbers are we talking about? I would suggest you generate a random graph with similar number of properties and similar values that you wish to have in your product. See how it performs.

Otherwise no caveats I would say. Oh, don't refer to internal Neo4j node IDs anywhere; unlike in a relational database, these get re-used.